# MySQL intersection of two tables

Tags: mysql, join

I need to implement a function which returns all the networks the installation is not part of. 
Following is my table and for example if my installation id is 1 and I need all the network ids where the installation is not part of then the result will be only `[9]`.

```
network_id  |   installation_id
-------------------------------
    1       |       1
    3       |       1
    2       |       1    
    2       |       2
    9       |       2
    2       |       3
```

I know this could be solved with a join query but I'm not sure how to implement it for the same table. This is what I've tried so far.

```
select * from network_installations where installation_id = 1;

network_id  |   installation_id
-------------------------------
    1       |       1
    2       |       1
    3       |       1

select * from network_installations where installation_id != 1;

network_id  |   installation_id
-------------------------------
    9       |       2
    2       |       2
    2       |       3
```

The intersection of the two tables will result the expected answer, i.e. `[9]`. But though we have `union`, `intersect` is not present in mysql. A solution to find the `intersection` of the above two queries or a tip to implement it with a `single query using join` will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to do this is to use a `network` table (which I presume exists):

```
select n.*
from network n
where not exists (select 1
                  from network_installation ni
                  where ni.network_id = n.network_id and
                        ni.installation_id = 1
                 );
```

If, somehow, you don't have a network table, you can replace the `from` clause with:

```
from (select distinct network_id from network_installation) n
```

EDIT:

You can do this in a single query with no subqueries, but a `join` is superfluous.  Just use `group by`:

```
select ni.network_id
from network_installation ni
group by ni.network_id
having sum(ni.installation_id = 1) = 0;
```

The `having` clause counts the number of matches for the given installation for each network id.  The `= 0` is saying that there are none.

Comment: This is a good one. I've got the networks table and the query resulted as I expected. But I wanted to do it in a single select (with help of join). Is that possible? @Gordon Linoff

Comment: Just one word, `AWESOME`. Was fighting with it for nearly couple of hours. If you don't mind, can you explain me the last line of the query please.

Comment: @DhiwaTdG . . . I'm surprised you accepted the answer with `left join`.  It can return multiple rows for each network id, but your question does not seem to be asking for duplicates:  "I need all the network ids where the installation is not part of then [sic]".

Answer (score 1):

Another solution using `OUTER JOIN`:

```
SELECT t1.network_id, t1.installation_id, t2.network_id, t2.installation_id
FROM tab t1 LEFT JOIN tab t2
    ON t1.network_id = t2.network_id AND t2.installation_id = 1
WHERE t2.network_id IS NULL
```

You can check at http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4798d/2

Comment: I already tried ur approach. Since I don't have a record where network_id is `null`, the query didn't work.

Comment: @DhiwaTdG It should work because it takes advantage of `LEFT JOIN`. There will be a record which `network_id IS NULL`. check [here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4798d/2)

Answer (score 0):

```
select * 
from network_installations 
where network_id in
    (select network_id 
     from network_installations 
     where installation_id = 1
     group by network_id )
```